# Consequences of quiting a masters program (because of a job) and later applying for PhD program

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path, masters

Suppose a student complete 1 year of a masters degree (2 year program). She then decides to accept a job. Later on, she wants to apply to a PhD program. Would it look bad if she didn't finish the masters program?

Comment: Are you talking about the same university (Master and PhD)?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/is-it-hard-to-start-phd-programme-after-leaving-to-work-in-indusry

Comment: @Stat-R: No a different university for each.

Comment: @RobbieThoms Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 4):

No, I do not think it would be a problem provided you work in a field close to your PhD area. If you get relevant experience, it helps to get into PhD.

Many university (at least in US) allow direct PhD admission for qualified BS students. So, if you are able to do some good work in your job, it can help you in applying for a PhD.

The reason I am emphasizing "relevant experience" since otherwise you **may** have to justify quitting the Masters program. The admission managers/professors may tend to suspect your staying for PhD.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing a directly a PhD after a Bc is a very smart move.

Changing course depending on the current need is a valid decision and people should understand it. So I would not worry about how it will look.